# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string' and TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, jinja2

I try to run /homepage

```
@app.route('/')
def index():   
    return redirect(url_for(homepage))


@app.route('/homepage')
def homepage():
    return render_template('fullcalendar.html')
```

Got that error:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

this error show up when i write in the address bar 127.0.0.1:5000/homepage:

```
  File "/home/pc/shudleApp1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 318, in url_for
if endpoint[:1] == ".":

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

fullcalendar.html

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename=css/fullcalendar.css') }}"/>
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename= css/fullcalendar.print.css') }}" />
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename=js/jquery-1.10.2.js' }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename=js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename=js/fullcalendar.js') }}"></script>
<script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `redirect(url_for(homepage))` you are passing to `url_for` the `homepage` which is your **function** and not your homepage endpoint.

You should pass `'/homepage'`

Comment: Now I get jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'fullcalendar' is undefined
The html file is in template where is the index.html file

Comment: your template is not correct. you are missing `'` in the `filename`